# Doesn't join work the other way around in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I am trying to run join on these two tables. 
This seems to work

```
 BIT_SEL_TBL_INFO.joins(:bit_sel_tbls)
```

But it doesn't seem to work the other way around.

```
BIT_SEL_TBL.joins(:bit_sel_tbl_infos)
```

It shows

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'BIT_SEL_TBL' to association named 'bit_sel_tbl_infos'; perhaps you misspelled it?


#bit_sel_tbl_info.rb
    class BIT_SEL_TBL_INFO < ExternalDbAccess
        self.table_name = "BIT_SEL_TBL_INFO"
        has_many :bit_sel_tbls, class_name: "BIT_SEL_TBL", primary_key: "BIT_SEL_TBL_NO", foreign_key: "BIT_SEL_TBL_NO"
    end

#bit_sel_tbl.rb
class BIT_SEL_TBL < ExternalDbAccess
    self.table_name = "BIT_SEL_TBL"
    self.primary_key = 'BIT_SEL_TBL_NO', 'FIELD_NO'
    belongs_to :bit_sel_tbl_info, class_name: "BIT_SEL_TBL_INFO", primary_key: "BIT_SEL_TBL_NO", foreign_key: "BIT_SEL_TBL_NO"
end
```

Comment: How about providing some more details on what your tables are?

Comment: i rectified the mistake @DerekBrown. A simple one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, noob mistake
Had to make it :bit_sel_tbl_info instead of :bit_sel_tbl_infos because it is belongs_to

```
BIT_SEL_TBL.joins(:bit_sel_tbl_info)
```